# Entity framework TPT hierarchy not working for deep hierarchy when reading values from database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have 3 tables:

```
Duty
Task :Duty
ProcessTask : Task
```

I'm using TPT hierarchy and everything seems fine when creating the database.  But when I read the values from the database, I'm not getting any values from the Duty table.  This is my query:

```
var tasks = _dbContext.Duties.OfType<Task>()
                             .OfType<ProcessTask>()
                             .Where(c => c.ParentID == id);
```

Only values from Task and ProcessTask is returned, although the SQL query returned all the correct values (I checked with SQL Profiler).

Why would it not map the first abstract class' fields?  Any help is much appreciated.

My source code:

```
public class Duty
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }        
    }

[Table("Task")]
    public class Task : Duty
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public int? Duration { get; set; }

        public int? NoOfRepeats { get; set; }
    }

[Table("ProcessTask")]
    public class ProcessTask : DigiBob.Model.Governance.Duties.Task
    {
        public int ProcessTaskTypeID { get; set; }
        public virtual ProcessTaskType ProcessTaskType { get; set; } //ProcessTasks

        public int? ParentID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ParentID")]
        public virtual ProcessTask Parent { get; set; }  //Children

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A short description is required")]
        [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "The maximum length for the short description is 150")]
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    }

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Duty> Duties { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: few more things - how do you insert / call - usage.

Comment: ^^ (how do you insert, which types etc.)

Comment: Are you aware that `.OfType<ProcessTask>()` removed all items that are not of type `ProcessTask`? You seem not to want that, yet you explicitly request this.

Comment: Yes, I only want ProcessTasks.  Problem is that the ID (from Duty) is 0 (zero) although the correct ID is returned from the database.

Comment: @NSGaga, the code for reading values are in the original post.  When iterating through tasks, later when I convert it to a viewmodel, I see that all the ID's are 0.

Comment: @NSGaga, I haven't done the insert yet.  Values currently in the database was added manually.

Comment: ok - I'm just seeing your `query` - you're actually asking only for those two types? Why don't you add the `.OfType<Duty>()` and try with that. That 'OfType' is translated into SQL directly with explicitly mapping to those two tables - as it's an explicit call. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was referencing the ID field incorrectly.  This is what I had:

```
public static ProcessTaskView ConvertToProcessTaskView(this ProcessTask processTask)
    {
        ProcessTaskView processTaskView = new ProcessTaskView();
        processTaskView.ShortDescription = processTask.ShortDescription;
        processTaskView.ProcessTaskTypeID = processTask.ProcessTaskTypeID;
        processTaskView.ID = processTask.ID;

        return processTaskView;
    }
```

This is the correct code.

```
public static ProcessTaskView ConvertToProcessTaskView(this Duty processTask)
        {
            ProcessTaskView processTaskView = new ProcessTaskView();
            processTaskView.ShortDescription = (processTask as ProcessTask).ShortDescription;
            processTaskView.ProcessTaskTypeID = (processTask as ProcessTask).ProcessTaskTypeID;
            processTaskView.ID = processTask.ID;

            return processTaskView;
        }
```

Note that I'm now passing in a Duty object and am having to specify what type of Duty it is to access properties of the ProcessTask.  Now the ID field has a value, not just 0.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

**Your query is wrong...** - otherwise your code should work fine

> What you're doing effectively - is just returning the `ProcessTask`-s.
>   (OfType selects only Tasks - but then you reapply
>   OfType to it - and further narrow that down.

```
// this returns just ProcessTask-s
IEnumerable<Duty> tasks = db.Duties
    .OfType<Task>()
    .OfType<ProcessTask>()
    .ToList();  

// this returns all Task-s (including processes)
tasks = db.Duties
    .OfType<Task>()
    // .OfType<ProcessTask>()
    .ToList();  

// this returns all Duties (including tasks, processes)
tasks = db.Duties
    .OfType<Duty>()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: NSGaga, I only want the list of ProcessTasks.  The first query is thus the correct one.  However I found my problem and will post it as an answer.  Your .ToList() bit helped me to know that the ID is in fact return, I'm just not referencing it correctly.